# python lists of lists: сгруппировать записи из sqlite по email

Tags: python, sqlite, python-2.x

Всем привет,

ищу совета по решению задачи, делаю выборку из бд sqlite, и в выборке повторяется электронный адрес клиента, чтоб не высылать два раза клиенту письмо, нужно высылать одним письмом.

вид вывода данных о клиенте:

```
email1|data1|data2
email2|data1|data2                             
email3|data1|data2                             
email1|data1|data2
```

если email1 существует то просто дабавить инфу уже к существующей записи, и так с другими адресами, идея в том чтоб клиент не получал спама из кучи писем, а все в одном, как можно реализовать такую функцию, допустим если я буду парсить адрес клиента в списке:`([-a-zA-Z0-9_.]+@\w+.\w+)`, то как создавать список на основании его мейла? и как грамотно реализовать такую функцию. Спасибо за советы.

Comment: Если я правильно понял, что вы хотите сделать, то первая идея - создавать мапу `{client1: [email1, email2, email3...], client2: [email4, email5, ...]}` и потом для каждого клиента отсылать почту, например, на первый email.

Comment: Покажите пример данных, выбираемых из базы.

Comment: email1|data1|data2
email2|data1|data2                             
email3|data1|data2                             
email1|data1|data2

Answer (score 0):

решил задачу таким образом,

когда вытягиваю данные о клиенте из бд, делаю еще раз запрос, но только почтовый адресс, и делаю обработку на повторения, если нет такого ключа то добавляю новую запись и тд.

```
mail_data = {}

if result_mail in mail_data:
   mail_data[result_mail] += (value)
   print("get it")
else:
   mail_data.update({key: value})
```